# Getting keyof typeof TypeScript Enum from number

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum:

```js
enum ReviewReportType {
  HARASSMENT = 6,
  INAPPROPRIATE = 7,
  UNKNOWN_PERSON = 3,
  FAKE_REVIEW = 8,
  OTHER = 5,
}
```

and a Type:

```js
export interface FirestoreReport {
  reviewId: string;
  type: keyof typeof ReviewReportType;
  message: string;
}
```

And I've got a payload coming from an API I want to transform to the `FirestoreReport` type:

```js
const payload = {
  type: 6,
  message: "foo",
  reviewId: "bar"
}
```

I'm curious how to idiomatically map the `type: 6` (which I can only ascertain to be of type `number` if I run the payload through `zod`) into the `keyof typeof ReviewReportType` so that I end up with:

```js
const report: FirestoreReport = {
  type: "HARASSMENT", 
  message: "foo",
  reviewId: "bar"
}
```

---

My failed attempt:

```js
const mapType = (type: number): keyof typeof ReviewReportType => {
  return ReviewReportType[type]
}
```

This gives me following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type "'HARASSMENT" | "INAPPROPRIATE"...'
```

Comment: TypeScript allows `const foo: ReviewReportType = ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT | ReviewReportType.INAPPROPRIATE` (bit operations on number enums), so `ReviewReportType[foo]` wouldn't return a `keyof typeof ReviewReportType`

Comment: Why do you need the key of the enum in the first place and not the enum itself ? –

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler
Because I want to store `type: HARASSMENT` in Firestore instead of `type: 6`.

Comment: @MartinSvoboda please let me know if any of these articles is helpful https://catchts.com/safe-enums

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) You're running into [ms/TS#38806](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38806), so the compiler won't infer such a type for you, you'd have to write your own type function to do it.  And note that you need to take into account `undefined` as a possible result.   Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WyeknW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I think the enum being unsafe is part of the problem.

Comment: @jcalz Could you write up the answer, please? What I'm looking for in the answer is an idiomatic way of dealing with the uncertainty of having a `number` coming from an API and making sure that either I successfully fetch the key of the enum or have a branch of code that guards against numbers that are not listed in that enum if that makes sense.



Note: I'll remove the screenshot in favour of a code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the [reverse mapping for numeric enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) is not strongly typed and is represented as a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) whose value type is `string`.  So if you index into a numeric enum with a `number` key, you will get a `string` output, as you noticed.  This is too widely typed in the case where you pass in a valid enum member:

```
const str: "HARASSMENT" = ReviewReportType[ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT];
//    ^^^ <-- error, Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"HARASSMENT"'
```

This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#38806](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38806), a feature request currently waiting for more community feedback.

And it's also too narrowly typed in the case where you pass in an invalid member, since it doesn't anticipate a possible `undefined` (unless you turn on [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) which most people don't do and isn't part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)):

```
const oops = ReviewReportType[123];
// const oops: string (but should really be string | undefined)
oops.toUpperCase(); // no compiler error but RUNTIME ERROR!
```

---

If you want to write a `mapType()` function that takes account of both of these in the "right" way, you can... but because the compiler doesn't handle it for you you'll need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `ReviewReportType[type]` is actually of the type you claim to return.

Note that we could just use your version with a type assertion, like this:

```
const mapType = (num: number) => ReviewReportType[num] as keyof typeof ReviewReportType;
```

but it has very similar limitations... you get `keyof typeof ReviewReportType` instead of `string`, but it's still too wide

```
const str: "HARASSMENT" = mapType(ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT); // still error
```

and too narrow

```
const oops = mapType(123);
// const oops: "HARASSMENT" | "INAPPROPRIATE" | "UNKNOWN_PERSON" | "FAKE_REVIEW" | "OTHER"
oops.toUpperCase(); // still no compiler error but RUNTIME ERROR!
```

so you would need to be careful with it.

---

Instead I'll write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) version of `mapType()` that is as close to accurate as I can make it:

```
const mapType = <N extends number>(num: N) => ReviewReportType[num] as
  { [P in keyof typeof ReviewReportType]: typeof ReviewReportType[P] extends N ? P : never }[
  keyof typeof ReviewReportType] | (`${N}` extends `${ReviewReportType}` ? never : undefined)
```

That's quite a mouthful, but I'll try to explain it.  The function is generic in `N` the `number`-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) type of `num`.  The return type is in two parts:

- The  `{ [P in keyof typeof ReviewReportType]: typeof ReviewReportType[P] extends N ? P : never }[keyof typeof ReviewReportType]` is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), where we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in order to distribute a type operation over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys in the `ReviewReportType` enum.  That operation is to check if the corresponding enum member is assignable to `N`.  If so we return the key, otherwise we return `never`.  So if `N` is `6`, then this will be `"HARASSMENT"` when the key is `"HARASSMENT"`, and `never` otherwise... the union of all of those is just `"HARASSMENT"`, which is what we want.  If `N` is wider, like `number`, you get all the keys (since each enum member extends number`).
- The `` (`${N}` extends `${ReviewReportType}` ? never : undefined) `` part checks to see if `N` can *fail* to be an enum member (I need to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to do this because numeric enums are considered narrower than the equivalent numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types); converting both sides to a `string` literal circumvents this).  If it can, then we want to add an `undefined` to the output type... otherwise we don't.

Put those two together and you get the closest I can get to accurate behavior:

```
  const str: "HARASSMENT" = mapType(ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT); // okay
```

That works now because `mapType(ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT)` returns `"HARASSMENT"`.

```
  const oops = mapType(123);
  // const oops: undefined
  oops.toUpperCase(); // compiler error now, oops is undefined
```

That is now a compiler error because `mapType(123)` returns `undefined`.

---

Now we can use this as desired:

```
const report: FirestoreReport = {
  type: mapType(ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT), // okay
  message: "foo",
  reviewId: "bar"
}
```

This succeeds because the compiler knows `ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT` is `6` and that `mapType(6)` is `"HARASSMENT"`.  You mentioned that you're passing stuff through `zod` (whatever that is ) so the compiler will not know this.  The compiler just knows it's some `number`:

```
function getSomeNumber(): number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
```

And so you'll get an error:

```
const report2: FirestoreReport = {
  type: mapType(getSomeNumber()), // error! could be undefined
  message: "",
  reviewId: ""
}
```

I contend that's the right behavior.  The compiler *should* warn you if it can't verify that you're not assigning `undefined` there.  You can fix that by using [the non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-):

```
const report3: FirestoreReport = {
  type: mapType(getSomeNumber())!, // you *assert* that it's not
  message: "",
  reviewId: ""
}
```

But... maybe you hate that?

---

If so then here's my final proposal.  Make the function `throw` if the return value is going to be `undefined`, and remove the `undefined` possibility from the return type:

```
const mapType = <N extends number>(num: N) => {
  const ret = ReviewReportType[num];
  if (typeof ret === "undefined") throw new Error("YOU GAVE ME " + num + " NOOOOOOOO!!!!! ");
  return ret as {
    [P in keyof typeof ReviewReportType]: typeof ReviewReportType[P] extends N ? P : never
  }[keyof typeof ReviewReportType];
};
```

Now you know that any code running after a call to `mapType()` will have some key of the enum:

```
const str: "HARASSMENT" = mapType(ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT); // okay
const oops = mapType(123);
// const oops: never;
oops.toUpperCase(); // compiler error now, oops is never
```

See that `oops` is of type `never` because the compiler knows control flow will never make it to that line.  And now this succeeds:

```
const report2: FirestoreReport = {
  type: mapType(getSomeNumber()), // okay
  message: "",
  reviewId: ""
}
console.log("YAY " + report2.type);
```

which is great; assuming `zod` never gives you random things like `getSomeNumber()` you'll be fine, and otherwise you'll get a runtime error before you make it out of `mapType()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsBuBLYB3OAHA9gJwC4BUBPdYKAbwFgAoKKACQEEYGBlFgWQFEA5fKAXigA2ADTVaASW4MACjJgB5eRIb5OAqAHYxNKAFVuAaW4KA6twD6MzjBYLuGgMw7aAMQaHOFmJwBqEzlMNAA4XKAV8OhsNAFYdAF9qalxsQnIk3QBjTBAAZ1wofOwALigAIkZmNi5eMo04JFQMHAJiYABtBuQ0YCw8IhIAOkrWDh58AF0AbnEoAHo52loAPVWoAB4AWk2oYGxsHBEoAdIAciLEEABzU6hEXKgQTAKAQ1zcxCuQF4AjABtSLhMFBcG0oKcKkxRjV8GVThlaNk8gVMJh0A9BF0mr0Wid2gBGABMjmmswWUCR+SgqPRpQu11mNNygyBenQJGwAGE3sAABQASim80WMAM+AkXCgNkUMAAhBl4hSXrhMgALKC8vbYfnpLI5XKYAGDP6YK6a-b86iJKjUS64PYAMxemVIrkQ2GA+RwwGaeF1tA9jRQEgAJnSUpcrjNdKCSKUANbAQiYB0gtop2AIbq+1okaO0CCe3IvK7AcPYSPR60ZSkFdAvQgml4hjSUGNtUqiWaF94lsvlB2osphQPdUOlMo-F7YMpW5Kpf0U-UFCAvdAnDS88AQUrbn57HX8AB8maDObx24mUDeUETydTseAGaxPT6ueA+aXyMKKQnI2q4x1IIq7rm0vIvuebTDFCAG8IKwo-ogfx-Ls+w4LMtbUmiGJQCBJy8kSjiCmSiyYUyf4wWMtRQAAPuUUiyPISgwCoah1HRZQGMYZiWNYtj2Ox5TuJ43h+AEpiCWUERRDAs66EyLKYGyHLcrkfLweSoq8BK6jSgocpWkqKrqua2qLpShrAMapqmcRVDWpheFgoI6wOMAAAe9ogCGDx7nsR5bpApTcIeJ4QTi-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-3oHPUP4ej+P-L8rKU9QMmYAV28al4JXytlT60Nk8XA69iybwPiOHq7syiHwyN8Hs9YXRQFcAxAAMq4fS7BdQImZiuAeJANCuWmpVXy8dsABW3MFUKi5LrfiTvUV6zcLyQFJLoWgiBUy8kKlARh-ABHlHJpTOGZQdTKwOCgR4qApRoRjmUAAmgoPQUAADiDBfDqElHUAA1I8SAUA9F1BMAoUxZiFCyksZYqAgBeDcAIx7YjPwBmAMnVOfCXGxToUsJKKU0r3jTCQLKZ4WH9QKl1U82YQkkCSuVGa3kHi1XqltaR8A9izFoK1DqD5wlS3fOwjJeCzpeMwkUCiVR7pATvvhXJJxoLlM+ujb6v1CDpPwVhdEQN758lBk4hCkNaQpL2L0hSrJ2Qox5AKRpS4sY402jPAmRN2kPFJutVJNtdCKm1sZemFpin6kstZdmuzyRKJUeozRUBJSEWquY25ZirGzAbvQqkPMWhnw7t6YW19Wm3wli9YJJUZb1PGJPBCP0-ocNwnbSBZRHbbyWO4oMsDPZyQKSdWgvsQD+0DqlR+I8KGx30WPBOrSk4pzThnLOOcY750zkXEuEAy6VxrnXT8Ty2mvLwK3VB7dBaXzfD3BFvzCF8jxRHAlr8P7gpaZCnsED+xwLCM4pF+84GPP+nkA5bNeSKIYAo8ohj3FvkJCyNo9cgA)

Comment: That's awesome! A very detailed answer, thanks! 

It's a shame that Typescript currently does not support this: `const str: "HARASSMENT" = ReviewReportType[ReviewReportType.HARASSMENT];
`

I've just recently learned about https://github.com/colinhacks/zod. As I'm using it to validate a potentially dirty API payload all Zod can give me is a number as a matter of fact. So right now I just need to plug your `mapType` function to further narrow down that type.

Really appreciate the detailed explanation. It all makes sense! 

Comment: I've added an additional answer that gives more context to what I was trying to achieve with the payload coming from API leveraging your `mapType` function.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @jcalz solution, if there's a payload we know virtually nothing about coming from the API and we want to map that to a certain type we can leverage https://github.com/colinhacks/zod to do the following:

```
export const APIPayloadSchema = z.object({
  type: z
    .number()
    .refine((type) => Object.values(ReviewReportType).includes(type), {
      message: 'type has to be an allowed number',
    })
    .transform((val) => mapType(val)),
  message: z.string(),
  reviewId: z.string(),
});

export type APIPayload = z.infer<typeof APIPayloadSchema>;
```

Notice the `transform` where we call the function that narrows down the `number` to `keyof typeof ReviewReportType`

We then parse the payload:

```js
const payload = {
  type: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  message: "Foo",
  reviewId: "Bar",
}

const parsed = APIPayloadSchema.parse(report)
```

And at this point we can safely build the desired object because `parsed.type` is a `keyof typeof ReviewReportType`:

```js
const report: FirestoreReport = {
  type: parsed.type, 
  message: parsed.message,
  reviewId: parsed.reviewId,
}
```